# React app doesn't load onsenui css files on chromium

Tags: reactjs, chromium, onsen-ui

I've got a really weird bug in a create-react-app application. Onsenui is used as a css framework. But when I try to run the app, either in production or on localhost on a chromium based browser, the framework doesn't get loaded. Both css and js aren't loaded. (Only the OnsenUI ones, other css and js is loaded correclty) I then have to refresh the page multiple times to make it work. It loads correctly on Firefox and Safari.

The problem persists on both my MacBook and my Windows PC. I'm not the original creator of the repo and it's already a few years old. I have however updated `onsenui, react-onsenui, react` to the newest version.

Unfortunately, I can't share the link to the page.

Comment: Can you try doing it without updating the packages? Im pretty sure that is the problem

Comment: Nope, updating the packages is what I tried to fix the problem. It didn't work with old versions either

Answer (score 0):

So, in the end, it's been all because of a pop-up blocking extension I had installed. I can't believe I haven't thought of it and I've been refreshing the page multiple times/had to use other browsers just because of this.

So if anyone ever sees this is the future with a similar problem, double check all your active extensions.